# Performance difference for showing/hiding popup. React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have two different ways of showing/hiding a popup in React. I am wondering if there is a performance difference between the two. I'm assuming the first way is more conventional.

**First way:** showing the popup based on a conditional statement in the return statement ([entire code can be found here](https://jsfiddle.net/9yeyw5ky/)):

```
{this.state.showPopup ? 
  <Popup
    text='Close Me'
    closePopup={this.togglePopup.bind(this)}
   />
   : null
}
```

**Second way:** Rendering on button click then unmounting on close click ([entire code can be found here](https://jsfiddle.net/debej0xL/1/)):

```
showPopup() {
  ReactDOM.render(
     <Popup
       text='Close Me'
     />,
     document.getElementById('popup')
   );
 }

closeClick() {
  ReactDOM.unmountComponentAtNode(document.getElementById('popup'));
}
```

Comment: I personally go for the first solution (which feels more natural to me) but im interested in the answer ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For experience, if you want maximize the performances, the best way is the 3rd you didn't mentioned: through CSS.

Acting on a class that display/hide the component make reconciliation easier and you go through lifecycle instantiation methods once.

Try something like:

```
className={this.props.shouldHide ? 'hidden' : ''}
```

[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/px1ztq7e/1/) from Anthony

Comment: Thanks for this. Here's the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/px1ztq7e/1/) if anyone is interested.